# Setting a custom control's member's property using a dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, windows-8.1

I have created a custom user control that is basically built of a grid, an image, and a textblock. I want to be able to set the source of the image and the text of the text block from properties of the user control. I have set up the following dependency properties; however, I want to know if there is a better way to set the child element's properties than the way below.

```
    public sealed partial class LabeledTile : UserControl
{
    public LabeledTile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(LabeledTile), new PropertyMetadata(null,(o, args) => ((LabeledTile) o).ImageSourceChanged((ImageSource)args.NewValue)));

    private void ImageSourceChanged(ImageSource newValue)
    {
        ImageElement.Source = newValue;
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(LabeledTile), new PropertyMetadata(null, (o, args) => ((LabeledTile)o).TextChanged((String)args.NewValue)));

    private void TextChanged(string newValue)
    {
        TextElement.Text = newValue;
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

This is my first time using a dependency property and I want to make sure I am on the track. It seems like more work than should be required. Also, are callbacks really the best way to set the value?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks about right to me, I had to do this when my I couldn't bind to the DP and have bound controls in my user control as well.